# haskell : calculated fields in custom data types

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to do something that is equivalent to having a field in a data type that is automatically calculated from other fields in the data type. For example:

```
data Grid = Grid
  { x :: Int
  , y :: Int
  , c = (x * y) :: Int
  }
```

and then 
`myGrid = Grid 5 6`

or does this have to be or can only be done with `Class`?

```
data Grid = Grid
  { x :: Int
  , y :: Int
  }

class Calculated a where
  c :: a -> Int

instance Calculated Grid where
  c g = x g * y g
```

Answer (score 5):

Without any additional requirement, that's simply a function.

```
c :: Grid -> Int
c g = x g * y g
```

Comment: To enhance your example, note that `x, y, c :: Grid -> Int` by construction, since the field names are simply accessor functions.

Answer (score 5):

If, for some reason, you want to pre-compute `c` and store it in the value, define a smart constructor.

```
data Grid = Grid {x :: Int, y :: Int, c :: Int}

mkGrid :: Int -> Int -> Grid
mkGrid x y = Grid x y (x * y)
```

There is a stricter separation of data and functions in Haskell than in an OO language. `data` only defines a new type, not the operations on that type. Record syntax only provides projections of the form `Grid -> x` for some type `x`; it doesn't let you define anything more complicated.

Comment: @matthias, also note that because Haskell is lazy, the `x * y` here is not computed until a `c` is requested, so there's no time cost to doing it this way. And unlike defining `c` as a bare function, this saves the result for future use.

Comment: Unless you hide the bare constructor, though, someone can update one of the fields thus: `grid {y=16}` but the value of `c` would not be updated.